# Using standard unix commands, how do you grab a bunch of lines?

Tags: unix, alias

I have several text files with this format:

```
name: john
address: bay area
phone: 6505561234
image: /work/myimage.png

name: stark
dob: 5AD
shirt color: red
physical address: Westros
phone model: S2
email id: me@stark.org

phone model: S2
name: tara
dob: 1ad
shirt color: red
physical address: Westros
email id: me@stark.org
```

There can be multiple 'person's or 'contact's. Let's say I want to find all persons with 'S2' phone model.

I can do a 'grep' - that would just return this:

```
phone model: S2
phone model: S2
```

I can use the before/after context on grep - but that's just a fixed number of lines before/after that get printed out. With a 'previous' context of 3, I might get something like this:

```
shirt color: red
physical address: Westros
phone model: S2
---
name: tara
dob: 1ad
phone model: S2
```

But that's not what I want. I want the entire 'record' to show up. Any clues on how to go about doing this with standard unix commands?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `awk`, but honestly it'd be easier to do this with other tools. Why do you need standard Unix tools? Can you use a scripting language like Ruby or Python as well? Those often come with all sorts of Linux distros.

Comment: I know you want standard Unix commands, but I'll just point out that [Recutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/recutils) allows you to make complex queries against data formatted in exactly this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n"} $0 ~ /PATTERN/ {print $0"\n---"}' record`

Just replace PATTERN with whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace your empty lines with `---`, your document is a valid YAML file. This nicely represents a record structure like you have.

```
perl -p -e 's/^$/---/g' input > test.yml
```

Then, to get the complete records:

```
ruby -e 'require "yaml"; 
YAML::load_documents(File.open("test.yml")) do |d| 
  puts d.to_yaml if d["phone model"] == "S2" rescue nil
end'
```

This prints:

```
---
name: stark
dob: 5AD
shirt color: red
physical address: Westros
phone model: S2
email id: me@stark.org
---
name: tara
dob: 1ad
phone model: S2
shirt color: red
physical address: Westros
email id: me@stark.org
```

<sub>Marked as CW since you were asking for standard Unix tools, which `ruby` obviously isn't. Works with Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3 and 2.0.0.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed) question I manages to find a way to do a multiline grep for the blocks:

```
grep -Pzo 'name:(..*\n)*phone model:.*S2.*(..*\n)*' filename \
 | sed 's/^name:/---\nname:/' \
 | tail -n +2
```

where  `(..*\n)*` is any number of contagious non-empty lines. `-P` enables perl syntax, `-z` allows newline searches and `-o` prints only the matches. Sed is used for separation and tail cuts the first line.

Comment: The record keys are unpredictable.

Comment: @Ярослав The assumption I made was that all records start with the name key. From the example I expected `this format` to mean 1. all records start with the key name 2. all keys are written on their own line 3. records are separated by an empty line. My solution works fine for that.

Comment: @Tim: My example suggests that it should always start with 'name' - that's not the case... I'll update my example.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with awk is pretty neat. Here is a possible solution with sed:

1. -n do not print anything
2. all non-empty lines are appended to the hold register
3. when an empty line is encountered, the hold register and pattern space are swapped

   - if the pattern space contains the string passed in as the first argument 
     to look4pattern(), the whole set of lines is printed.
4. same as 3. for the last line (can't know if last line is empty)

---

```
$ look4pattern() { 
    sed -n '
    /^$/!{H}; 
    /^$/{ x ; /'$1'/p }; 
       ${ x ; /'$1'/p }
  ' < records.txt
  }
```

---

```
$ look4pattern S2

name: stark
dob: 5AD
shirt color: red
physical address: Westros
phone model: S2
email id: me@stark.org

name: tara
dob: 1ad
phone model: S2
shirt color: red
physical address: Westros
email id: me@stark.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Records separated by blank lines is actually a common format for fortune files, and (at least in the version of fortune I have, fortune-mod on Arch Linux) there is a `-m` option that prints all fortunes (records) matching a regex. So something like this:

```
fortune -m "model: S2"
```

and it will print all your records.